# Проверьте индикатор онлайна с числовым показателем отсутствия

Tags: php

Написал маленькую плюшку на php, код выглядит ужасно, но надо главное узнать...есть где ошибки, и где...

```
<?php
$smpaoad = "1532589999";

if (!empty($smpaoad)) {
    if (date('U') <= $smpaoad + 300) {
        $RTY = "Онлайн";
    } else {
        $lolxd = (date('U') - $smpaoad);
        if ($lolxd < 3600) {
            $zero = ($lolxd / 60);
            $RTY = round($zero);
            $tyu = ($RTY % 10);
            if (11 > $RTY || (19 < $RTY)) {
                if ($tyu == "0") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "1") {
                    $note = "минуту";//21 минуту / 1 минуту *назад
                } elseif ($tyu == "2") {
                    $note = "минуты";
                } elseif ($tyu == "3") {
                    $note = "минуты";
                } elseif ($tyu == "4") {
                    $note = "минуты";
                } elseif ($tyu == "5") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "6") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "7") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "8") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "9") {
                    $note = "минут";
                }
            } else {
                if ($tyu == "0") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "1") {
                    $note = "минут";//11 минут
                } elseif ($tyu == "2") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "3") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "4") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "5") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "6") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "7") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "8") {
                    $note = "минут";
                } elseif ($tyu == "9") {
                    $note = "минут";
                }
            }
            $hrea = "назад";
        } elseif (($lolxd >= 3600) && ($lolxd <= 10800)) {
            $zeros = ($lolxd / 3600);
            $RTY = round($zeros);
            $tyus = ($RTY % 10);
            if ($tyus == "1") {
                $note = "час";
            } elseif ($tyus == "2") {
                $note = "часа";
            } elseif ($tyus == "3") {
                $note = "часа";
            }
            $hrea = "назад";
        } elseif (($lolxd >= 10800) && ($lolxd <= 86400)) {
            if (date("j") == date("j", $smpaoad)) {
                $note = "";
                $RTY = "в " . date("G:i:s", $smpaoad);
                $hrea = "";
            } else {
                $note = "";
                $RTY = "вчера в " . date("G:i:s", $smpaoad);
                $hrea = "";
            }
        } elseif ($lolxd >= 86400) {
            $RTY = date("d m Y", $smpaoad);
        }
        $trus = "был ";
    }
}
echo $trus . $RTY . " " . $note . " " . $hrea;
//время онлайн****
```

если правильно, то окей... (не нашёл другого решения, вот и написал свой)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Предлагаю хорошо подумать об именах переменных и использовании пробелов в коде.

Comment: Мне надо узнать, правильная ли информация отображается...или нет

Comment: Запустите и посмотрите.

Comment: понял что надо, надо потом с поправкой на юзерскую дату выдавать

Comment: `if (11 > $RTY && (19 < $RTY)) {` - меньше 11 и больше 19? всегда false

Comment: упсь, простите...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё у вас верно, кроме первого условия на минуты. Но можно упростить код до примерно такого (не запускал, не проверял, но результат должен выдаваться такой же как у вас):

```
$lastActiveTime = 1532589999;

if ($lastActiveTime) {
    if (time() <= $lastActiveTime + 300) {
        $RTY = "Онлайн";
    } else {
        $timeDiff = time() - $lastActiveTime;
        if ($timeDiff < 1 * 60 * 60) {
            $note = plural(round($timeDiff / 60), ['минуту', 'минуты', 'минут']);
            $hrea = "назад";
        } elseif ($timeDiff <= 3 * 60 * 60) {
            $note = plural(round($timeDiff / (60 * 60)), ['час', 'часа', 'часов']);
            $hrea = "назад";
        } elseif ($timeDiff <= 24 * 60 * 60) {
            $note = "";
            $hrea = "";
            $RTY = "в " . date("G:i:s", $lastActiveTime);
            if (date("j") !== date("j", $lastActiveTime)) {
                $RTY = "вчера " . $RTY;
            }
        } else {
            $RTY = date("d m Y", $lastActiveTime);
        }
        $trus = "был ";
    }
}
echo $trus . $RTY . " " . $note . " " . $hrea;

// @copy http://dimox.name/plural-form-of-nouns/
function plural($num, $words)
{
    $cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
    return $num . " " .$words[($num % 100 > 4 && $num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($num % 10, 5)]];
}
```

Comment: спасибо, хорошее решение, но  вот время в минутах с последнего визита не выводится, ток склонение ..вот ошибка <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: RTY in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
был  минуту назад

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев можешь дописать в предпоследней строке между `return $words` само это время `return $num . " " . $words`, должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё отлично работает!

Comment: Хм, странная ошибка... Добавил <script>var moscow_offset = -3 * 60*60; 
var user_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60; 
var offset = user_offset + Math.abs(moscow_offset);
document.cookie = "CR_=" +  offset;</script> На выходе получается адекватная юникс метка, но код кидает  это Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function plural() in D:\\pages\group.php:21 Stack trace: #0 D:\\index.php(38): include() #1 {main} thrown in D:\\pages\group.php вот обработ.    $taras = -$_COOKIE['CR_'];
  $smpaoad = $smpaoad->online;
   $hap = ($smpaoad + $taras);
   $lastActiveTime = $hap;